# how to avoid bower not recognised as an internal command?

Tags: node.js, windows, bower, bower-install

Just cloned bower into my nodemodules directory. I have added this path to the enviromentvariable path:

```
C:\mydir\nodejs\node_modules\bower
```

When I open a command window and run bower -v I get an error?

```
'bower' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

How can I rectify this error?

Comment: You could try using the full path as a tempory workaround (e.g. `"C:\mydir\nodejs\node_modules\bower" -v`).

Answer (score 0):

I've had issues when installing bower on external hard drives. Make sure you're calling bower -v from the same drive you have it installed. Maybe a restart of your system would help?